# Can someone please explain the process of using Lorentz force to separate aluminium sheets

Tags: electromagnetism

I work for Jaguar/Land Rover, we have an issue with aluminium panels that are delivered to us in stacks. The panels stick together and are difficult to separate. The current method is to blow air in between the panels and hope that works. I was doing some research and found a patent for a design that uses a series of magnets and contact electrodes to produce a motion of the top panel in way of Lorentz force and then use suction pads to remove the top panel. I would simply like to understand the science behind this, and if anyone knows the practicality of it.

Comment: Black air = blow air ?

Comment: Switching on the electromagnets it will be induced an eddy current in the top sheet and then a magnetic field between the top and the next sheet and by this an eddy current in the second sheet in opposite direction to the top sheet. You get an elevating top sheet. Something like that.

Comment: More on [aluminium and magnetism](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10827/is-aluminium-magnetic).

Comment: Yes sorry that should of been blow air not black air.

Comment: Can you add a link to the patent?

Comment: I have the Patent identification number: EP1302422 A1

Comment: This is the website address that i found the patent through. https://www.google.com/patents/EP1302422A1?dq=inassignee:%22Asm+Dimatec+Ingenieria+S+A%22&cl=en